# Avoiding RequireJS changing global registering of other frameworks

Tags: knockout.js, requirejs

I was looking for a javascript framework that would help me load in javascript asynchronously so I could make controls I could share between applications & make sure the different controls share their referenced frameworks without the main application needing to know which libraries are needded. I've been looking at requirejs and I like it quite a bit, but I found when I added it into an application that relied on KnockoutJS the "ko" global wasn't declared anymore.

Presumably this is because KnockoutJS decided I had an AMD and that therefore it'd leave the global namespace alone. I'd be fine with that if I'd loaded it with RequireJS but it's not so great if it was loaded by a script tag. The obvious answer is don't load it that way, but the problem arises if an existing app hasn't been written for AMD and I want to add requirejs to facilitate my shared controls and it breaks the existing app.

I could probably make a workaround to put knockout back in the global namespace, but I'm guessing knockoutjs isn't alone in this behaviour, just the first one I found testing.

I'm quite willing to use shim to expose non-AMD into AMD methods, but I don't want to have adding RequireJS to the page impact other code which isn't explicitly referencing it. Is there anything like jQuery's no-conflict mode for RequireJS or alternatively a similar framework that won't have undesired side-effects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't configure RequireJS to do that because this isn't something RequireJS is doing.

Knockout checks if RequireJS is available and changes the way it's binding - this is the [code](https://github.com/knockout/knockout/blob/master/build/fragments/amd-pre.js) doing that.

And there's already been a [bug](https://github.com/knockout/knockout/issues/478) written against this that's basically closed with "working as designed".

Comment: I'm not talking about using a define(['knockoutjs'], I'm talking about just referencing it via a script tag & having it not load properly cause require's already in. I guess essentially it's about mix&match'ing AMD in controls with regular scripts in the parent application (Which I thought I could do but it seems like you just can't). Perhaps requirejs isn't the right framework for the job...

Comment: I will reiterate again - this has nothing to do with RequireJS directly - this is how Knockout has implemented it's loading code.  The code checks for either CommonJS (node) or AMD (RequireJS) module specs and loads Knockout as a module in the detected module system. Otherwise it puts the ko object in the global namespace. If you're using a module system and still want 'ko' in the global namespace, it's up to you to add it yourself.  Again, you have to do this to work around the way Knockout is loading itself, not RequireJS.

Comment: I can see it's knockoutjs's code doing it mate, I even said that in my original question. But it still means end of the day if I take unknown website "X" and add requirejs to it, there's a significant chance the website will break. Regardless of the root cause, adding requirejs triggers a crash on a site using commonly used frameworks. If that's the case and there's no workaround then I guess it's unusable in my use-case cause it seems 100% AMD or 0% AMD is the only use case that's truly supported when combining these frameworks.

Comment: If you take unknown website "X" and add or change *anything* in it, there's a significant chance the website will break. The workaround in this case is to bind 'ko' to the global namespace yourself.

Comment: If that was true, there'd be no such thing as portable libraries. Sure there's always some risk, but I'd put it to you most well-made sites won't break as a result of for example adding jQuery in noconflict mode. The same doesn't seem to be true of requirejs. And no, binding "ko" globally yourself won't work. If the existing page is referencing it with a `<script>` tag after requirejs is loaded it actually crashes completely & doesn't register itself as a module or a global. If it only didn't register global if you loaded it via a requirejs then it wouldn't be an issue at all.